# Hide only bottom action bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Currently, I have a split action bar, and there is an edit text near the bottom of the screen.

When I click on the edit text, the keyboard shows up, but the bottom action bar ALSO shows up on top of the keyboard, making it cluttered. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I hide only the bottom action bar when I click on edit text?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       //bottom action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.defaultbottom_tabs, menu);

    setActionBar();
    return true;
}


    // custom layout top action bar
private void setActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // displaying custom ActionBar
    View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home_top,null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` attribute to the `Activity` that shows your `EditText`. Alternatively, if you **really** want to do this in code, you can find the split action bar `View` by using `Resources.getIdentifier`.

```
    final int id = getResources().getIdentifier("split_action_bar", "id", "android");
    final View splitActionBar = findViewById(id);
    if (splitActionBar != null) {
        // Toggle the visibility
    }
```

Comment: Author neither accepted the answer nor voted it up. I checked it out and it works like a charm - used API 19. Thanks

Comment: I get a white line instead of the bottom (split) action bar. What I did is set the visibility to `gone`. Is there a higher view that contains the split action bar?